# three.js lighting doesn't appear to work as I am expecting

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9XCWc/1/ which is the html/js from a php generated terrain.

The issue is that it does not appear to be rendering the shadow etc as I would expect.

This is my lighting setup.

```
  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  // directional lighting
  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  directionalLight.position.set(400, 200, 3000).normalize();
  scene.add(directionalLight);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of effects are you trying to get?

You are currently using `MeshBasicMaterial`. The documentation says about it:

```
MeshBasicMaterial
A material for drawing geometries in a simple shaded (flat or wireframe) way.
```

You should check [**this example**](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials). It shows the different materials you can get and what they'll look like.

For instance [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/dmTZg/2/) compares a `MeshBasicMaterial` and a `MeshLambertMaterial`.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

You are creating a mesh vertex per vertex but you never create the normals. Yet, if you want such a shadowing effect, a MeshLambertMaterial needs to compute the normals to calculate the light variations:

- The reflection is calculated by taking the dot product of the surface's normal vector, N, and a normalized light-direction vector, L, pointing from the surface to the light source.([*wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance))).

There is a `geometry.computeFaceNormals();` function to help you with that.

You can have a look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/gKy8J/1/).

Plus, you should check the [**JS array objects**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp) + using some [**for loop**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

Hope this helps

Comment: I was expecting the portions facing towards the camera to appear lighter and the portions facing away to appear darker - to appear like an actual terrain.I've updated the fiddle to change the material to Lambert but it just appears like a white area with no definition.

Comment: Thanks - taking the lighting & face normals into account seemed to work. The jsfiddle isn't written in succinct js due to being dynamically produced from php.